# Use Django Subquery as FROM table or CTE in order to have a Window over an aggregate?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I am trying to sum costs within groups, and then add a cumulative cost over multiple groups. Simplified:

```py
class Cost(Model):
    year = IntegerField()
    month = IntegerField()
    cost = DecimalField()
```

```sql
select 
  "year",
  "month",
  month_total,
  sum(month_total) over (
    partition by 1 order by "year", "month" rows between unbounded preceding and current row
  ) as cum_total
from (
  select "year", "month", sum("cost") as month_total
  from app_cost
  group by "year", "month"
) as innerq
order by "year", "month"
```

But I can't work out how to write it with Django's ORM:

```py
innerq = Cost.objects.values("year", "month").annotate(month_total=Sum("cost"))
```

is all very well, but then if I do:

```py
outerq = innerq.annotate(
    cum_total=Window(
        expression=Sum("month_total"),
        partition_by=[Value(1)],
        order_by=[F("year"), F("month")],
        frame=RowRange(None, 0),  # UNBOUNDED PRECEDING -> CURRENT ROW
    ),
)
```

I get a:

> FieldError: Cannot compute Sum('month_total'): 'month_total' is an aggregate

How can I force the queryset `innerq` into a subquery, as in my SQL above? (I am aware of `Subquery`, I just haven't found a way to apply it here.)

Comment: Why would you like to do this? Your SQL is clear, standard, easy to read and does the job. Why smudge it into a cryptic proprietary syntax that does not even reflect the declarative nature of the query?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm If it were up to me, I'd probably not use the Django ORM for anything, but my colleagues might feel the same way about plain SQL, and it is a largely Django application, so I'm trying to write it in cryptic proprietrary syntax if possible.

Comment: I see. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've been [struggling](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/query-a-json-formset-using-orm/26003) with a similar problem and just found the [django-cte](https://github.com/dimagi/django-cte) project which seems to confirm that the out-of-the-box ORM does not have the needed support, and offers a way forward using its `With`.

Using it, I believe a simplified version of your problem could be solved with something like this:

```
from django_cte import With

class Cost(Model):
    # pre-req!
    objects = CTEManager()
    year = IntegerField()
    month = IntegerField()
    cost = DecimalField()

cte = With(
    Cost.objects
    .values("year", "month", "month_total")
    .annotate(month_total=Sum("cost"))
)

innerq = cte.join(Cost, region=cte.col.year).with_cte(cte)...
```

(My use case is a bit different than yours). See the [docs](https://dimagi.github.io/django-cte/) for more.